# How to interact with unexpected ? Expect

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to get a script to get an automation.
There my example `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Would you like tea ?"
read answer
echo $answer
echo "Would you like cup ?"
read answer
echo $answer
echo "Would you like cake ?"
read answer
echo $answer
echo "Would you like car ?"
read answer
echo $answer
```

I want to answer to questions what I know with expect and interact with user to whom I didn't expect.
In my example, I know I will expected the question about tea and car. The two other will be unexpected and need an interact with the user.

There are my script.exp :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn ./script.sh
match_max 100000

while true {
        expect {
                "tea"   {send -- "yes\r" ; exp_continue }
                "car"   {send -- "no\r" ; exp_continue }
                -re "(.*)\[\r\n]"   interact  {
                                       "yes" { send -- "yes\n"; exp_continue }
                                       "no"  { send -- "no\n"; exp_continue }
                                    }
                }
                exp_continue
        }

}

expect eof
```

But once I get into interact, I can't get out. 
I tried "break" but it go on the end.
I read more than once the man page of Expect but can't find a solution.

Can you help me to sort this ?

To get the context of this, I will need to upgrade over 200 VMs (debian 7 to 9) soon. I am trying to make that operation less pain by respond to the apt-get upgrade command. Can't use --force-yes because some answer need "no".

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have entered `interact` on its own (without any pattern matching options).

In order to interpret the "yes" or "no" as a pattern you need to enclose the `interact` with an additional brace-pair:

```
-re "(.*)\[\r\n]"   { interact  {
                       "yes" { send -- "yes\n"; exp_continue }
                       "no"  { send -- "no\n"; exp_continue }
                    } }
```

Comment: It is interesting to note that the left square bracket *must* be escaped with a backslash.  However, the closing square bracket does not need to be escaped.  It can be, but that's not necessary: once the [ bracket is passed literally to the expect command it is then interpreted as the start of a [ ] pair.